# Does Tableau Public support live connections?

Tags: csv, tableau

Are live connections available in Tableau Public? I have seen a "Live connection" checkbox in a few tutorials, but it is missing from Tableau Public 2020.3.1 - is it missing from the Public version by design or has it been moved/removed from new versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, with one exception:

> Can I save to Tableau Public a workbook with a live connection to a data source?
>
> Tableau Public only supports extracted data sources and does not support live connections to data. However, authors have the option to allow Tableau Public to automatically refresh data sources connecting to Google Sheets every 24 hours. For all other data sources (like Excel or a CSV) automatic refresh on Tableau Public is not supported."

See:
https://community.tableau.com/s/tableau-public-faq#subhead17

Answer (score 0):

octosquidopus! Tableau supports live connections but can be exclusions, especially if the required connection goes through VPN or multiple user API addresses. In this case, Tableau will give you an error message. The best way to avoid these kinds of errors is using additional software like the Jira application that can receive additional connections. I recommend you visit this site [alphaservesp.com](https://www.alphaservesp.com/blog/tableau-connector-for-jira-installation-guide/), for more information regarding the Tableau application. I'm sure you will find more useful information to help you in the future, especially if you plan to use Tableau more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).